# How do you get the stereographic projection on a circle of radius $r$ if you know it on $S^1$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, stereographic-projections

I know the formulas for stereographic projection on $S^1$, we have two functions, $\varphi_N : S^1 \setminus \{(0,1)\}\to \mathbb{R}$, $\varphi_N(x^1, x^2)=\frac{x^1}{1-x^2}$ and $\varphi_S : S^1 \setminus \{(0,-1)\}\to \mathbb{R}$, $\varphi_S(x^1, x^2)=\frac{x^1}{1+x^2}$, and that's about it.

But now I am given a circle of radius $r>0$ and I want to find the formulas for stereographic projection here. I thought that maybe I should just take the projection of the circle to $S^1$, i.e. $p(x^1, x^2)=\left(\frac{x^1}{r}, \frac{x^2}{r}\right)$, and compose it with $\varphi_S$ and $\varphi_N$. Is this right?

Comment: Presumably when you write *THE formulas for stereographic projection* [caps intended on the word *the*], you have in mind some independent definition of stereographic projection. If so, please give that definition. If not, then it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Stereographic projection is defined on the unit circle so if you have some points not on the unit circle you'll have to explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thanks for pointing this out, I didn't realize that. What I basically want is to find an atlas (in the sense of differential geometry) on that circle of radius $r$. I know that for $S^1$ the stereographic projection is the way to go (now I realized that there are more types of such projections, but my teachers always only use the stereopgraphic projections that I indicated and that's why I forgot), so I wanted to adapt those charts to a circle of radius $r$ instead of the unit circle.

Comment: @LeeMosher I explained in the comment above what I am trying to do. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: You can just scale it down then scale it up after you calculate the point in $\mathbb{R}$ you're looking for. So this might look like $r \varphi (x^1/r , x^2 /r)$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thanks, but why would I also need to scale it up?